# Searching an XML document in MarkLogic for processing-instruction

Tags: xquery, marklogic, processing-instruction

I have the following code:

```
cts:and-query((
cts:element-word-query(xs:QName("primaryie"), $textname, "case-insensitive"),
cts:element-query(xs:QName("beginpage"),
cts:and-query(()))
))
```

but would like to add a `cts:or-query` to find the hightlighed "docpage" but can't figure out what to use. I tried `cts:element-query` but I think it isn't an element. It seems like a marker or something. Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Hello Mike,It would be nice to see a sample of the XML that you are trying to query.

Comment: docpage is a processing-instruction. I don't think you can use cts on those. XPath might work, but can be heavy in MarkLogic. Can you elaborate on the context?

Comment: I have 3000 XML documents on a MarkLogic server. I am trying to find only documents that have <primaryie> and either <beginpage> or "docpage." The user types a term, such as "abdomen" and it searches all the docs for that term in <primaryie>. I then get the page numbers from the index. I want to search the document for docpage num="the page number". I then search from that page number for the term from the index so I can add a markup code to that word.

Answer (score 2):

There is not currently a way to create an index on a `processing-instruction()` (using a path-range-index or otherwise).

If you are already leveraging the [envelope pattern](https://developer.marklogic.com/blog/envelope-design-pattern), you could materialize that `processing-instruction()` as an element in your envelope i.e. `<docpage num="i"/>` and then use [`cts:element-attribute-value-query()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:element-attribute-value-query)

```
cts:and-query((
  cts:element-word-query(xs:QName("primaryie"), $textname, "case-insensitive"),
  cts:or-query((
    cts:element-query(xs:QName("beginpage"),
    cts:element-attribute-value-query(xs:QName("docpage"), xs:QName("num"), "i")
  ))
))
```

Or you could create a document property and then use [`cts:properties-fragment-query()`](http://docs.marklogic.com/cts:properties-fragment-query)

```
cts:and-query((
  cts:element-word-query(xs:QName("primaryie"), $textname, "case-insensitive"),
  cts:or-query((
    cts:element-query(xs:QName("beginpage"),
    cts:document-fragment-query(
      cts:element-attribute-value-query(xs:QName("docpage"), xs:QName("num"), "i")
    )
  ))
))
```

Otherwise, you would need to perform filtering via XPath on the search results.

```
cts:search(doc(),
  cts:element-word-query(xs:QName("primaryie"), $textname, "case-insensitive")
)[book/(beginpage or processing-instruction("docpage") = 'num="i"')]
```

This would require filtering(reading through the matched docs), so how quickly this query responds will depend upon the number of documents that are returned from the search criteria, and the limits you place on how many docs to return.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Mads. I'll give it a try on Tuesday when I get back to work.